# How to get an element value in DOM using selenium2 java

Tags: javascript, java, html, dom, selenium-webdriver

Here is the HTML code

```html
<form id="save" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="id2">
      <div>
        <div id="id3">
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <input id="TotalAmt" class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" name="TotalAmt">
```

My DOM is like this

[image: DOM]

I want to get the highlighted property value from the DOM. It's not in the HTML. Is there a way to get that text using JavascriptExecutor or by another way? I'm using Selenium2 and Java as my programming language.

Comment: is "property value" the same as the "value" attribute?

Comment: No. In HTML "value" attribute is null but in DOM the "property value" is "4730.60"

Comment: try using `elem.getAttribute("value")`;

Comment: I have tried it. But we cannot get the value using "getAttribute" as the "value" is null.

Comment: Is the value that you entered? the "property value" has the value entered in "value" ? Maybe there is another way of doing this, a work around, like saving the value and used to fill the input and then to compare it.